# How to bind an array of objects using options pattern in .NET 7 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I want to bind an array of objects using the options pattern in .NET 7. The JSON part in the **appsettings.json** is as shown below:

```
"AdminEmails": [
    {
      "Name": "John",
      "Email": "john@gmail"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Daniel",
      "Email": "daniel@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
```

There are classes named **AdminEmail** and **AdminEmailsOptions** as shown below:

```
public class AdminEmail
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class AdminEmailsOptions
{
    public AdminEmail[] AdminEmails { get; set; }
}
```

The class is registered in the **program.cs** as shown below:

```
builder.Services.Configure<AdminEmailsOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AdminEmails"));
```

I need to access the appsettings.json values in the HomeController but the _adminEmailsOptions is null.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
    private readonly AdminEmailsOptions _adminEmailsOptions;
    public HomeController(IOptions<AdminEmailsOptions> adminEmailsOptions)
    {            
        _adminEmailsOptions = adminEmailsOptions.Value;
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me to achieve the goal or how to get the array of objects using the options pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AdminEmails` is holding a collection, not an object with collection property, so you need to change the code to bind to `List<AdminEmail>` (binding directly to array has not worked for me):

```
builder.Services.Configure<List<AdminEmail>>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AdminEmails"));
```

Or try binding on previous level:

```
builder.Services.Configure<AdminEmailsOptions>(builder.Configuration);
```

Or introduce one more level in the config.